# Regex for IPv4 Routable address only

Tags: regex, ip-address

What is a regex that can find a routable IPv4 addresses only? EG, does not match 192.0.2.1/24, 127.0.0.1, etc. Google seems to only find the all too common 'is an ip address' regex.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an obvious use case for regex to me. Any reason you *have* to do this using a regex?

Comment: I figured it was the best way, but from Anon.'s answer I think there is a better way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to implement business rules in a regex is a bad idea.

Just parse the IP address, and check whether it satisfies your criteria in code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0)\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!\.0$)(?<!\.255$)$
```

It correctly **doesn't match** this invalid ips:

```
999.999.999.999.
108.0.0.01
0.1.2.3
00.0000.00.00
192.168.1.1
912.456.123.123
.3.3.3.0
3.2.2.0
192.168.0.0
18.16.0.0
```

It **doesn't match** local IPs:

```
172.16.0.9
172.16.4.1
172.17.1.1
127.0.0.2
10.0.1.5
10.0.0.1
10.155.155.155
10.255.255.254
172.16.0.4
172.16.0.1
172.17.1.1
172.31.254.254
```

Finally it **doesn't match** broadcast IPs:

```
60.123.247.255
196.168.255.255
10.255.255.255
192.168.255.255
```

Every other IP i've tested is a match so far, but I haven't done it thoroughly, so there might be some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a regex anyway, not efficiently.  Parse it, then check against the special-case addresses (multicast, RFC 1918, etc).