# Regex for IPv4 address, excluding private IPs

Tags: regex

I need to do some data validation on a field in a piece of software which only supports validation through regular expressions. I have been searching to find a regex for what I'm looking for, however it seems all of the responses just give a better way to do it. I have to do it this way, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Basically, the regex should accept any valid IPv4 address, excluding the following:

From 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255

From 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255

From 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255

I found this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284750/regex-for-ipv4-routable-address-only), however nobody was actually able to answer it.

I've been using [this](http://www.regexr.com/) website to try validating the regex. I started with

```
\b(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b
```

which I also found on the website. This works great for IPv4 addresses, but I am now unsure how to exclude the private addresses. Does anyone have a regex for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You will want to read http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html. Then you can easily build it on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) checking for them ( `(?!(10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.|192\.168))` ) right at the front, giving you:

```
\b(?!(10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.|192\.168))(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b
```

Assuming the software you are refering to supports lookarounds, of course.

Comment: I tried inputting this into that website to check but it is failing. I see what you are trying to do, but I don't exactly understand where to put the negative lookaheads or what the \b part does.

Comment: `\b` is a word break.  the lookahead should go right after the `\b`.  I provided the full regex, you can see it in action here: http://regexr.com/3amgm .   If it isn't working, good chance your software doesn't support lookarounds, in which case you are going to have a much tougher time of it.  Might help if you explain a bitmore about this mystery software.  Hard to know what is going to work, if we don't know what flavor of regex is in play.

Comment: @femtoRgon, 172.161.1.1 is excluded.  What is the correct way to exclude 172.16, but accept 172.161 or 172.16[\d]?

Comment: @techguy2000 - Ought to just be able to add a `\.` after that section of the lookahead (see edit)

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon!  I changed 3[0-2] to 3[0-1] since 172.32.0.0 is public: https://regexr.com/5ehl1

Comment: @femtoRgon, in your code, if I put in 1.1.1.1.1, it will still match the first 4 1's.  Do you know what changes are needed to not match anything if there are more than 4 Octets?

Comment: @techguy2000 Sure, just use [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (^ and $) instead of word boundaries (\b) at the beginning and end

Comment: Thanks for your help @femtoRgon!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case,
If you are trying for a IP, CIDR validation (Ex: `10.123.33.12/32`). try the below:

```
  validateCIDRAddress(data: string) {
    let isValid = false;
    const regexp = /^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$/;
    if (data && regexp.test(data)) {
      isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions are not the best method to specify IPv4 address ranges. As you add more and more ranges, your regexp would get more and more convoluted and error-prone.

Instead, you should consider using [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation.

Here are the CIDR notations for your example ranges:

```
From 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 -> 10.0.0.0/8
From 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255 -> 172.16.0.0/12
From 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255 -> 192.168.0.0/16
```

There is probably a library for your programming language of choice that allows you to easily determine whether a given input IPv4 address is valid for a given list of CIDR addresses.

EDIT:

I failed to notice that the OP is apparently using some sort of software that cannot validate that an IP address is within a range using any technique other than a regexp. So, if that's really the case, then obviously my alternative using CIDR notation will not work for this particular case. However, I stand by my answer that using CIDR notation to encode IP address ranges is generally a better option than using regular expressions, when CIDR notation is an option.

Comment: "*a piece of software which only supports validation through regular expressions*"