# Regex to ONLY match PUBLIC IPv4 address

Tags: regex

At first, I thought it's easy to find the regex which only matches public IPv4 address on the Internet. However, after tons of googling,I got nothing,so I try
to write the regex,as follows(Perl flavor),

```
[0-9]\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}|
1[1-9]\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}|
[2-9][0-9]\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}|
1[0-6][0-9]\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}|
17[0-1]\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}|
172\.0\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.)[0-9]{1,3}|
172\.1[0-5]\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.)[0-9]{1,3}|
(172\.3[2-9]\.)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.)[0-9]{1,3}|
(172\.[4-9][0-9]\.)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.)[0-9]{1,3}|
...
```

The regex seems inaccurate and inefficient , does someone have a better way to write the regex?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net#RE-net-IPv4 would match an IPv4 address. I wouldn't put the "public" check into the regex.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? `127\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` isnt public !!

Comment: I've broken the string by `.`s then checked each value in the past `if (($sections[0] == 192 && $sections[1] == 168) || ($sections[0] == 172 && ($sections[1] >= 16 && $sections[1] <= 32)) || ($sections[0] == 10)) {`. What language are you running this in? (also that conditional is checking the inverse of your request; if that matches it is private).

Comment: @chris85 You just check private IP address , not public IP address.

Comment: Yea, it's the inverse, the language you are working with doesn't support `else`?

Comment: @Agawa001 172 is NOT 127. :)

Comment: @chris85 I am using an editor to search, not a language.

Comment: There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284750/regex-for-ipv4-routable-address-only?rq=1

Comment: @Ramana the link doesn't solve my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284147/608639)

Answer (score 12):

Try this one:

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0)\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

It correctly **doesn't match** this invalid ips:

```
999.999.999.999.
108.0.0.01
0.1.2.3
00.0000.00.00
192.168.l.1
912.456.123.123
.3.3.3.0
192.168.o.0
```

It **doesn't match** local IPs:

```
172.16.0.9
172.16.4.1
172.17.1.1
127.0.0.2
10.0.1.5
10.0.0.1
10.155.155.155
10.255.255.254
172.16.0.4
172.16.0.1
172.17.1.1
172.31.254.254
192.168.1.2
192.168.254.0
```

And matches pretty much every IP i've tested. Can't say I really done a lot of testing, so i'm welcome for suggestions

Comment: What about private link-local addresses `169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255 = 169.254.0.0/16` since 2005? https://regex101.com/r/GWcMlF/1

Comment: Actually they are 169.254.1.1 to 169.254.254.255, which brings unneeded complexity to this quick & dirty ipv4 address validation. An obvious way to do it without excluding first & last 256 addresses would be putting (?<!169\.254) right after (?<!192\.168) block, as mentioned in your regex101 link.

Comment: The first useful is 169.254.0.1. The last useful is 169.254.255.254 - IIRC. Apart from that, I agree. BTW: Is it really necessary to have that twice: `(?<!172\.(?:16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))`?

Comment: this is wrong.... 60.123.247.255 is a VALID ip address, not a broadcast. So is 60.123.247.0.

Comment: @LivioZanolPuppim you're entirely correct.

Answer (score 7):

I would much rather capture each octet and check if the subnet is private in code rather than with regex. However, I'm intrigued by your question.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses), there are 3 ranges of private IP address.

```
10.0.0.0    - 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0  - 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

Now assuming that you don't have crazy IP-like strings, like `55.300.666.1`, you can use negative lookbehind to do what you want:

```
(\d+)(?<!10)\.(\d+)(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1]))\.(\d+)\.(\d+)
```

Let's see that again, with some line breaks added for clarity:

```
(\d+)(?<!10)
\.(\d+)(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1]))
\.(\d+)\.(\d+)
```

The first line checks that the first octet is not `10`. The second line checks that the first 2 octerts are not `192.168` or between `172.16` and `172.31`. The third line has nothing special. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dH7lL0/1)

**PS:** I do know that `127.0.0.1` is localhost but I have no idea if it's private (I'm not a network engineer). You may have to improvise as needed.

Comment: I used your regex statement in Solarwinds to find devices with public IP addresses. It worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: The entire IP range of 127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.255 is not considered a 'public IP address', and should not be matched for public IP ranges.

Comment: This worked as an improvised first line to not match local host: `(\d+)(?<!10)(?<!127)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to validate purely public IPv4 addresses, we can eliminate all of the [Reserved IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv4) as follows:

- `0.0.0.0/8`: Current network
- `10.0.0.0/8`: Private network
- `100.64.0.0/10`: Shared Address Space
- `127.0.0.0/8`: Loopback
- `169.254.0.0/16`: Link-local
- `172.16.0.0/12`: Private network
- `192.0.0.0/24`: IETF Protocol Assignments
- `192.0.2.0/24`: TEST-NET-1, documentation and examples
- `192.88.99.0/24`: IPv6 to IPv4 relay (includes 2002::/16)
- `192.168.0.0/16`: Private network
- `198.18.0.0/15`: Network benchmark tests
- `198.51.100.0/24`: TEST-NET-2, documentation and examples
- `203.0.113.0/24`: TEST-NET-3, documentation and examples
- `224.0.0.0/4`: IP multicast (former Class D network)
- `240.0.0.0/4`: Reserved (former Class E network)
- `255.255.255.255`: Broadcast

*(list taken from [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IPv4#/Special-use_addresses))*

---

This can be put into a straightforward regex that doesn't use lookbehinds (and hence, the regex can be used in JavaScript):

```
(^0\.)|(^10\.)|(^100\.6[4-9]\.)|(^100\.[7-9]\d\.)|(^100\.1[0-1]\d\.)|(^100\.12[0-7]\.)|(^127\.)|(^169\.254\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.0\.0\.)|(^192\.0\.2\.)|(^192\.88\.99\.)|(^192\.168\.)|(^198\.1[8-9]\.)|(^198\.51\.100\.)|(^203.0\.113\.)|(^22[4-9]\.)|(^23[0-9]\.)|(^24[0-9]\.)|(^25[0-5]\.)
```

Likewise, this assumes that you have already validated beforehand that it actually is a valid IPv4 address.

Comment: What about broadcast IP addresses? https://regex101.com/r/wxULXv/1

Comment: 60.123.247.255 is a VALID ip address, not a broadcast. So is 60.123.247.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0)\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!\.255$)(?<!\b255.255.255.0\b)(?<!\b255.255.255.242\b)$
```

A slightly different solution that removes false positive addresses if you grep through firewall configs. removes common masks 255.255.255.0 and 255.255.255.242. add and remove as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Anubioz's + Irvin Lim=

```
^(?!^0\.)(?!^10\.)(?!^100\.6[4-9]\.)(?!^100\.[7-9]\d\.)(?!^100\.1[0-1]\d\.)(?!^100\.12[0-7]\.)(?!^127\.)(?!^169\.254\.)(?!^172\.1[6-9]\.)(?!^172\.2[0-9]\.)(?!^172\.3[0-1]\.)(?!^192\.0\.0\.)(?!^192\.0\.2\.)(?!^192\.88\.99\.)(?!^192\.168\.)(?!^198\.1[8-9]\.)(?!^198\.51\.100\.)(?!^203.0\.113\.)(?!^22[4-9]\.)(?!^23[0-9]\.)(?!^24[0-9]\.)(?!^25[0-5]\.)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))$
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWtlj.png

(without broadcast)